# Let $H_1, H_2, \dots, H_n$ be subgroups of $G$ satisfying three conditions. Show that $H_i\simeq H_j$

Tags: group-theory

Let $n\geq 3$ be a positive integer, and let $H_1,H_2,\dots,H_n$ be subgroups of $G$ satisfying;

1. $H_i\bigcap H_j=\{e\}$ is the identity element of $G$.
2. $H_iH_j=G$ for all $i\neq j$
3. For all $1\leq i,j\leq n$, $x\in H_i$, $y\in H_j$, we have $xy=yx$.

Show that $H_i\simeq H_j$ for all $i\neq j$.

I already know that $G=H_i\times H_j$ for all $i\neq j$. Then we get $G=H_i\times H_k$,and $G=H_j\times H_k$ when all $i,j,k$ are distinct. Thus $H_i\times H_k\simeq H_j\times H_k$. By $(3)$, we can see that $H_i, H_j, H_k$ are abelian.

If $H_i, H_j, H_k$ are finitely generated abelian subgroups of $G$, then $H_i\simeq H_j$ for all $i\neq j$.

But if $H_i, H_j, H_k$ are not all finitely generated abelian subgroups of $G$. (i.e. some or one of them are infinitely generated). I don't know how to proceed. Maybe we don't even need to solve these cases individually.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! my friend. your question is nice. but, it was painful editing your latex. please check the edits i made :)

Comment: $G = H_i \times H_j = H_i \times H_k \Rightarrow H_j \cong G/H_i \cong H_k$.

Comment: Oh~ I got it. Thank you.

Comment: @DerekHolt This is an answer, not a comment.